# Center align text in button within an tablelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

im trying to center align the text in the buttons on the screen, 
but so far all other posts regarding this matter do not work. 
any guess on how this can be achieved?

img link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH5Jc.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/play_grid"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/TopTableMarginSize">

    <TableRow 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/one" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize" 
            android:text="@string/nr1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/two" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize" 
            android:text="@string/nr2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/three" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:text="@string/nr3"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/four" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize" 
            android:text="@string/nr4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/five" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize" 
            android:text="@string/nr5"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/six" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:text="@string/nr6"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/seven" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize" 
            android:text="@string/nr7"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/eight" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize" 
            android:text="@string/nr8"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/nine" 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/TileSize"
            android:text="@string/nr9"
            android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/information" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/info_label"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/TopTextViewMarginSize"
    android:textSize="@dimen/TextFontSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
 <Button >
 <Button >
 <Button >
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this code for table row instead of yours.

Comment: thnx for the fast response, but adding that changed noting noticeable. the text is still at the same spot.

Comment: Once again thanks for your reply. oddly enough it makes no difference. I've build up the whole layout from scratch this way but with no change at all (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/GEPbv.png) I've looked in to font padding also with no result yet.